# Pass adb options/parameters to android gradle tasks (install, connectedCheck, etc)

Tags: android, adb, android-gradle-plugin

In the Android gradle plugin there are options for aapt and dex but I can't find where I can pass parameters to the adb used by tasks such as install and connectedCheck (and any other that would use adb to complete).

My problem is that I want to pass the -H flag pointing to a remote adb. The use case is to run my tests on a remote machine (and then maybe, machineS). I believe this was possible with Android Maven plugin but I want to do it in Gradle now.

I have access to both machines and have tested that I can list and install a package using the -H flag but it seems like that android-gradle is hard coding 127.0.0.1.

If anyone has a working example of running the tests on different adb hosts could you please share it here?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found a working solution by setting the environment variable `ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_ADDRESS`. I discovered it by digging through the [adb source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/commandline.cpp#1442).

You can see it also checks for `ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT` and `ANDROID_SERIAL` if you need to change either of those too.

Comment: This has been a long time :) But last I checked, Gradle was overwriting these variables (not ADB). I don't have the setup right now to reproduce this, but let's see what other people find.

Comment: Yeah, I take it back. This works fine for ADB, but Gradle is overwriting the host and it doesn't check the ADB host environment variable like it does for the port one.

Comment: Well... it has been like that for more than 3 years now :) Thanks for your support anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing the same problem. [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15366108/1257326) wrote a java app (linked in the third comment to the post) that forwards adb connections to a remote adb server. This might be a workaround?

Comment: I'd have added a comment instead if i had enough reputation. However, I do think that the solution in my link might be a good alternate approach to the problem for some.

Comment: P.S. The question was "If anyone has a working example of running the tests on different adb hosts could you please share it here?" The app linked in my answer actually allows precisely for that.