# Debugging on Android device connected to another PC over network/VPN

Tags: android, tcp, adb, remote-debugging, remote-desktop

I am trying to connect to an Android device connected to my laptop while developing and writing code via Remote Desktop and VPN on my work machine.

What I would like to do is to build on the remote machine and deploy to android phone via VPN connection to android device connected on the laptop via USB.

I tried following another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18551325/1079311) but was unable to get it to work.

Here is what I did so far.

- Forked ADB server on laptop:

  ```
  adb -a -P 5037 fork-server server&
  ```
- Connected to my server from desktop:

  ```
  adb connect mylaptopname:5038
  ```

**UPDATE**

I also tried following instructions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256599/1079311) I also do not see my devices.

I run this on the laptop `adb -a -P <PORT_NUMBER> nodaemon server` and then run this on the desktop where I develop `adb -H <REMOTE_IP> -P <PORT_NUMBER> devices` I still do not see the device.

I get this back: `List of devices attached` and nothing else, indicating it does not see any devices.

The connection was successful but my desktop still does not see the phone.

Comment: It does not seem that you are following the post you linked. `adb connect` does not do what you think it is supposed to do.

Comment: Could you please explain? Do you know what I should be doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can deploying/execute application on a remotely running device using adb (android platform-tools)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245597/how-i-can-deploying-execute-application-on-a-remotely-running-device-using-adb)

Comment: When I follow the instructions from this post I also do not see my devices. I run this on the laptop `adb -a -P <PORT_NUMBER>` nodaemon server and then run this on the desktop where I develop    `adb -H <REMOTE_IP> -P <PORT_NUMBER>` devices I still do not see the device. I get this back: `List of devices attached` and nothing else, indicating it does not see any devices.