# Install unknown source apk on ChromeOs

Tags: android, androidappsonchromeos

I updated my Chromebook Asus Flip this morning to get the Play Store.
My Chromebook has the M53dev channel version installed. 
It is working well. I can install and run Android apps downloaded from the Play Store.

I would like to test my app but in the Security settings, I do not have the option to allow Unknown Source. I tried anyway to install my apk (that I downloaded using the Android Google Drive app) but the installation is blocked.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It doesn't work by copying the APK over via USB drive. The Downloads folder shown in the Chrome OS Files app is the same location as the Downloads folder in the Android realm (on what amounts to external storage). However, attempting to install the app via an Android file manager results in the "need to allow unknown sources" dialog, leading you back to the problem that you reported.

Comment: What about "adb shell settings put global install_non_market_apps 1"? But that leads to the question how to do adb..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426150/what-will-be-the-side-loading-and-debugging-mechanism-for-android-apps-on-chrome for information about how to enable the "unknown sources" switch.