# How to trigger uiautomator tests on local android device from remote host?

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, android-uiautomator

I want to run `uiautomator` tests on a cloud host but those tests needs to run against my local android device.(not on some AWS device farm or equivalent)

My scenario is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278429/how-to-set-up-adb-for-remote-machine-development-and-local-device-deployment) but I don't want to involve my local host, so that I can shut down my local PC once the test starts on remote host, for that it has to be able to communicate with the android mobile over the public internet(not looking for a port forwarding solution).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)