# How to get adb access to a local device in a codespace ? (local to remote, vscode)

Tags: adb, port, vscode-remote

I wanted to develop on Android and I needed adb access from a GitHub codespace (for some pretty random stuff) and I hadn't found a way to share the local adb server / local ip / local usb connection.

As I'm using vscode, I tried to share a port from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdqsW.png) but forwarded ports are only server to local (I didn't found a way to do a local to server)

I also searched on internet but no solution was proposed...

I mention [How to set up ADB for remote machine development and local device deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278429) because it is an interesting answer but I don't want to open a non-secure port.

Comment: Hello, Yes, I got a solution by extracting the command line running ssh, and editing the command to add a reverse port. It was not so difficult but this almost always requiere an external tool (process explorer, process hacker, even with some cmdline it is possible, just search on the internet how to extract the command line).

Comment: Ok thanks I’ll give a try