# How to set up iPhoneXR for remote machine development and local device deployment

Tags: iphone, usb, hyper-v

I need to use itunes on my hyper-v VM, and my iphoneXR plugging on my local PC .

I tried to use [USB Redirector RDP Edition](https://www.incentivespro.com/usb-redirector-rdp.html) , but it couldnt get the iphoneXR, it just got its photo...

also,i tried [adb for remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278429/how-to-set-up-adb-for-remote-machine-development-and-local-device-deployment), but adb is just used for android..

thanks in advance for every reply!